# Post on a logged in users facebook wall

Tags: php, json, facebook

Hey all, I've created a widget that will essentially unlock a music track, providing you post to either your twitter account, or facebook wall.

I've signed up through facebook connect and I am able to successfully post onto my own wall... but the functionality I'm looking for is to be able to take ones username and password and automatically log in to facebook, and send my desired message.  Like I said, it posts on my wall successfully, it's just not using the username and password from the field to log in to their respective facebooks and post.

```
    <?php

$facename = $_POST['facename'];
$facepass = $_POST['facepass'];
define('FB_APIKEY', 'my_api_key');

define('FB_SECRET', 'my_secret_phrase_');

define('FB_SESSION', 'my_session_id');

require_once('facebook.php');

echo "post on wall";

try {

$facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);

$facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;

$fetch = array('friends' =>

array('pattern' => '.*',

'query' => "select uid2 from friend where uid1={$facename}"));

echo $facebook->api_client->admin_setAppProperties(array('preload_fql' => json_encode($fetch)));

$message = 'I downloaded Automatic Loveletter\'s new single \'To Die For\' here!';

if( $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message))

echo "Added on FB Wall";

} catch(Exception $e) {

echo $e . "<br />";

}

?>
```

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated! Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook's API is not really designed to be able to post like Twitter's API is (or used to be)

To post on another user's wall, they have to authorize your application to make posts to their wall. Ideally, they will never give you their username or password. Ever.

Also note that Twitter's API is removing Basic HTTP Authentication. Meaning that you will either have to send the user to the Twitter Home Page with a URL-Encoded `status` parameter to set the message that will be pre-filled in, or the user will have to use OAuth to authorize your application.

Comment: I actually believe that you are able to with facebook connect.  I just can't seem to put it all together.. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions